# Error creating a defined controller in STS

Tags: java, exception, controller, runtime-error, spring-tool-suite

I am working on the Spring Tool Suite IDE.
My Project structure is shown here.

[image: project structure]

But when I try to run the controller, I get this following error.

> WARN : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'textEditorController' defined in file [F:\STS\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.4.SR1\base-instance\wtpwebapps\PostGres\WEB-INF\classes\com\postgres\controllers\TextEditorController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.postgres.controllers.TextEditorController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Spring-Module.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Spring-Module.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>   ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'textEditorController' defined in file [F:\STS\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.4.SR1\base-instance\wtpwebapps\PostGres\WEB-INF\classes\com\postgres\controllers\TextEditorController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.postgres.controllers.TextEditorController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Spring-Module.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Spring-Module.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

`TextEditorController.java` class is shown below.

```
package com.postgres.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.postgres.dao.CustomerDao;
import com.postgres.models.Customer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.JSONPObject;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class TextEditorController {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");
    CustomerDao customerDAO = (CustomerDao) context.getBean("CustomerDao");

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/editor", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {

        //ApplicationContext context =
                //new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");

           // CustomerDao customerDAO = (CustomerDao) context.getBean("CustomerDao");
           // Customer customer = new Customer(5, "mkyong",28);
           // customerDAO.insert();

           // Customer customer1 = customerDAO.findByCustomerId(1);
           // System.out.println(customer1);

        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        return "TextEditor";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value= "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String add(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {

        String queryString = request.getParameter("query");
        String msg = customerDAO.insert(queryString);
      System.out.println(msg);

    return msg;

 }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/result", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String result(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {

        Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

        String queryString = request.getParameter("query");

        map = customerDAO.findByCustomerId(queryString);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String element = gson.toJson(map);


                return element;


 }
    @RequestMapping(value= "/tables", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String tables(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {

        Map<String, List<String>> alvalues = new  HashMap<String, List<String>>();;  
        String queryString = request.getParameter("query");
    //  ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");

        //CustomerDao customerDAO = (CustomerDao) context.getBean("CustomerDao");
        alvalues = customerDAO.getAllTables();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String element = gson.toJson(alvalues);
            System.out.println(element);

                return element;


 }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/queryplan", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String queryplan(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {

        ArrayList<String> alvalues = new ArrayList<String>();    
        String queryString = request.getParameter("query");
        //ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");

        //CustomerDao customerDAO = (CustomerDao) context.getBean("CustomerDao");
        alvalues = customerDAO.getQueryPlans(queryString);

        customerDAO.getQueryPlans(queryString);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String response1= gson.toJson(alvalues);
        System.out.println(response1);

        return response1;


 }


    @RequestMapping(value= "/setDatabase", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String setDatabase(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {

        String database = request.getParameter("dataBase");
        //ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");
        //CustomerDao customerDAO = (CustomerDao) context.getBean("CustomerDao");
        String statement = customerDAO.setDefaultDatabse(database);

        return statement;



 }

}
```

Hence, due to this error, my browser throws the following exception.

[image: error]

Any suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated

Comment: It is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Spring-Module.xml] . it is possible your config is not able to find file Spring-Module.xml

Comment: If so, what exactly will be a fix ?

Comment: Show us the path of file "Spring-Module.xml"

Comment: The xml file seems to be present in the direct view, but am unable to find it within the project structure : http://imgur.com/a/3V3fI

Comment: But under the project structure this is what I currently have: http://imgur.com/a/ghLVe

Comment: Check if the file present in src/main/resources? you are looking it under src/main/webapp/resources+

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152993/discussion-between-raju-sharma-and-nayantara-jeyaraj).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding present in the code. In your controller, there is no need to instantiate a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext for some XML file and then use that to get a specific bean. This is not what dependency injection is all about.

In case you definitely want to use XML definitions for your Spring app, you should define your beans in there (if you want to) and use @Autowired, for example, to inject the CustomerDAO instance into your controller.

The better solution would be to forget about XML configs all together and start to use Spring Boot to implement your web app. There are millions of examples out there how to do that, including a number of guides (https://spring.io/guides) and a great project page to get started at http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Hope that helps!!!